# Biblatex does not print inbook book title

Tags: biblatex

I recently started using biblatex and have an extensive bibliograpy file created with bibtex in mind. I compiled my bibliography and notice that `InBook` looses the book title. As can be seen in the image below only **In:** gets printed where the book title should be.
[image: Example of formatting]

Here is the MWE I used to create this.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear-comp,sorting=nyt,mincitenames=1,maxcitenames=2,url=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\author{Minime}
\begin{document}
\parencite{Verwijst2013}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And this is the format of the entry in the bib file:

```
@InBook{Verwijst2013,
  Title           = {Development of Sustainable Willow Short Rotation Forestry in Northern Europe},
  Author          = {Theo Verwijst and Anneli Lundkvist and Stina Edelfeldt and Johannes Albertsson},
  Chapter         = {19},
  Editor          = {Dr. Miodrag Darko Matovic},
  Pages           = {479--502},
  Publisher       = {INTECH open},
  Year            = {2013},
  Note            = {Published: April 30, 2013 under CC BY 3.0 license.},
  book            = {Biomass Now - Sustainable Growth and Use},
  Doi             = {10.5772/55072 },
  File            = {Verwijst2013.pdf:Blandat material/Verwijst2013.pdf:PDF}
}
```

Is there some special treatment by biblatex of InBook, or formatting that I am missing?

Comment: The name of the field is "booktitle" not "book". Check the biblatex documentation about the available field names.

Comment: On a completely unrelated note: Normally academic titles and degrees are not given in the bibliography, so `editor = {Miodrag Darko Matovic},` would be preferred over `editor = {Dr. Miodrag Darko Matovic},`. You also have a space in your DOI field, though this might not have any impact, it looks odd, make it read `doi = {10.5772/55072}`. Plus, you might think about whether the entry type `@incollection` might not be better suited to what you have here (I, for one, would definitely prefer `@incollection` over `@inbook` here)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thankyou. Of course that remediates it. What a stupid misstake. Book is not even a valid bibtex field :/

Comment: Per the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) a `@inbook` refers to "A part of a book which forms a self-contained unit with its own title", p. 8; while `@incollection` is for "A contribution to a collection which forms a self-contained unit with a distinct author and title. The `author` refers to the `title`, the `editor` to the `booktitle`, i.e., the title of the collection.", p. 9.

Comment: @moewe Yes, you are absolutely right. I still have a lot of cleaning up to do in my bibliography file. Right now my priority no 1 is however getting bibliography formatting right :) A lot of these strange formatting issues sneak into the bib file when I download bibtex files from different publishers.  Scopus adds a lot of junk that is really disturbing in the bibliography output. I am very new to biblatex (1 day young), but I am trying to learn about the new possibilitied.  `@incollection` indeed seems like a better option here. Thankyou.

Comment: @moewe You just confused me. This is an article in a book with a common theme. Does what you just say mean `@inbook` is what should be used here?

Comment: Nope, maybe I should have also discussed what distinguishes a, `@book` "[a] single-volume book with one or more authors where the authors share credit for
the work as a whole", from a `@collection`, "[a] single-volume collection with multiple, self-contained contributions by distinct authors which have their own title. The work as a whole has no overall author but it will usually have an editor."; that is the main point here: "Biomass Now - Sustainable Growth and Use" is definitely a `@collection`. Naturally `@inbook` just is a part of a `@book` and `@incollection` a part of a `@collection`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I will read up on the manual soon, but unfortunately don't have the time right now as I have to deliver my thesis within two weeks.  Sorry about the stupid questions and thank you for your help.

Comment: One needs to be extremely attentive when downloading `.bib` files from the internet, often these contain unfortunate constructs, or simply wrong uses of certain fields. One has to do a lot of manual sifting through these sources afterwards if one wants to follow best practice.

Comment: That's all right. The question is: What do we do with this question now? A answer would look quite forlorn just saying: "Use `booktitle` and not `book`".

Comment: I agree. I should be sent of to the pile of stupid questions. But Ulrike Fischers answer did help me move on. However, I am sure there will be other people like me in the future that will benefit from simply reading "Use `booktitle` and not `book`" on here.  They will come, courtesy of google. The saddest part about this whole thing is that I don't even know how to promote answers on this forum :(

Comment: If you truly feel that this question is worthwhile, it would be customary to ask the commenter who answered your question in the comment to convert their comment into a fully-fledged answer. I'm not sure though how many people there are bound to be with the exact same problem (I have never seen anyone using `book` as a filed before) requiring the same solution.

Comment: You are right. Most people probably don't want to show stupid things like that. But, hypothetically, how do I ask UlrikeFischer to make her comment an answer? I see no messaging mechanism in here, except for the commentary field.

Comment: Why, you did this already when you typed @moewe at the beginning of one of your comments. The message is then delivered to the recipients inbox.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer If you would like you could turn your comment to my `inbook` question into an answer. Although it was a stupid question, your answer was spot on. I  will up-vote it if you choose to do so. It will show when I have earned 15 points in reputation.

Comment: @niclasericsson: Btw: It may have been a stupid error, but the question was very good. You showed all necessary informations in a clear way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the field is `booktitle` not `book`. Check the biblatex documentation about the available field names. It contains a long and useful list.